# Ruby how do i get current class name after super

Tags: ruby

For debugging purpose, i want to output current class name when i initialize a new object. So, this is what i have done.

```
class Base
  def initialize
      puts "line 2: " + self.class.to_s
  end
end

class Custom < Base
  def initialize
      puts "line 1: " + self.class.to_s
      super
  end
end
```

The problem is in the console, the output is

```
line 1: Custom
line 2: Custom
```

I understand `self` is an object of `Custom`. My question is how to get `Base#initialize` to print `Base`? So that my final output will be

```
line 1: Custom
line 2: Base
```

And when i initialize a Base object, it will print `line 2: Base` as well.

Comment: you can not add object to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a class is also a module, you can use [`Module.nesting`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting).

Also, to make sure you don't get `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Class into String`, you should use string interpolation :

```
class Base
  def initialize
    puts "line 2: #{Module.nesting.first}"
  end
end

class Custom < Base
  def initialize
    puts "line 1: #{Module.nesting.first}"
    super
  end
end

Custom.new
# line 1: Custom
# line 2: Base
Base.new
# line 2: Base
```

Answer (score 1):

Have I missed something?

```
class Base
  def initialize
    puts "line 2: Base"
  end
end

class Custom < Base
  def initialize
    puts "line 1: Custom"
    super
  end
end

Custom.new
  # line 1: Custom
  # line 2: Base
Base.new
  # line 2: Base
```

Comment: Yes, KISS FTW :)